# Pandas add sum based on dupliacte column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For the below dataframe df

```
Filename                                   Language    
Repo/Repo_3/.travis.yml                    YAML        20
Repo/Repo_3/backup_automater_services.py   Python      18
Repo/Repo_3/batch_file_rename.py           Python      33
Repo/Repo_3/cbd_pennies.                   C           26
Repo/Repo_3/cbd_rand.                      C           19
Repo/Repo_3/cbd_rand_dist.                 C           20
Repo/Repo_3/chaos.py                       Python       8
Repo/Repo_3/chapter02/item01/Provider.jav  Java         4
Repo/Repo_3/chapter02/item01/Service.jav   Java         3
Repo/Repo_3/chapter02/item01/Services.jav  Java        25
```

Trying to find out a way to find sum for duplicate in column of language.
Sum of All C language or Python

```
Filename                                   Language    Sum of All  
Repo/Repo_3                                YAML        20 
Repo/Repo_3                                Python      118
Repo/Repo_3                                C           120
Repo/Repo_3                                Java        125
```

Trying to use groupby but no luck

```
df.groupby(['Filename', 'Language'])['Code Lines'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with a `groupby`. But how do you intend on retaining the Filenames when you're aggregating on another column?

I'd recommend extracting the absolute directory paths from the Filename using `os.path.split` and grouping on Filename as well as Language.

```
import os

(df.assign(Filename=[os.path.split(v)[0] for v in df.Filename])
   .groupby(['Filename', 'Language'])
   .sum()
   .reset_index())

                       Filename Language  Value
0                   Repo/Repo_3        C     65
1                   Repo/Repo_3   Python     59
2                   Repo/Repo_3     YAML     20
3  Repo/Repo_3/chapter02/item01     Java     32
```

Comment: worked perfectly had a error 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Value' so changed it (df.assign(Filename=[os.path.split(v)[0] for v in df.Filename])
   .groupby(['Filename', 'Language'])
   .sum()
   .reset_index())

Answer (score 1):

The `Filename` that you're grouping by isn't the same for the rows you are trying to combine. You either want to remove that from the `groupby` or add a new column which *is* the same for all rows.

For just the dataframe you showed:

```
df.groupby(['Language']).sum()

      Code Lines
Language            
C                 65
Java              32
Python            59
YAML              20
```

The `apply` statement splits the name by `/` on each file and rejoins only the first two words, so adjust that as needed if your whole dataframe doesn't follow that convention.

And with a new column:

```
df['Repo'] = df['Filename'].apply(lambda st: '/'.join(st.split('/')[:2]))

df.groupby(['Repo', 'Language']).sum()

                  Code Lines
Repo        Language            

Repo/Repo_3 C                 65
            Java              32
            Python            59
            YAML              20
```